# How to automatically run a command after logging in on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, x11

xinput set-prop 13 298 0 1

I want to run this command automatically in order to disable mouse acceleration. This was easily done in various ways on Debian 8, but everything has changed in Stretch, and I've tried everything I can think of.

This command needs to run after X has started up. (So, not when booting, but on login.)

Or if someone knows of a more permanent way to completely disable mouse acceleration in Debian 9? (Most likely making use of libinput?) Either way, I appreciate any input. Thanks!

Update: For a DE, I am using the default X11 Debian Desktop Environment.

Comment: Which DE are you using? Most DEs have some way of setting startup applications (which can include scripts).

Answer (score 3):

If you are still using X and not Wayland, then the options are

1) edit `xorg.conf` with a proper section for your device to set the property. Details depend on the device.

2) configure your display manager (`xdm`, `kdm`, `gdm`, `lightdm`, whatever) to run this after the X server starts, details depend on the display manager used.

3) Make sure your display manager runs `.xsession` or a similar file on startup, execute command there.

You also shouldn't use `xinput` with hard-coded numeric ids; the numbers are not guaranteed to be the same across boots or server restarts.

If the property is one of the mouse acceleration properties (no way to guess with the numbers), I'd recommend to read `man xorg.conf`, section *Pointer Acceleration*, and set those you want in your `xorg.conf` (choice 1).